# Take next N rows recursively and sequentially from sql table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have two tables "main" and "moved". "main" table has records from where I move 3 rows sequentially to "moved" table by executing a stored procedure. So every time I execute the stored procedure it should check to see the next set of 3 rows are sequentially read from "main" table from the row of last move happened and inserted into "moved" table.

```
select rowid from @main
rowid
-----------------------
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now when I execute the query, it should take the 3 rows from "main" table and insert into "moved" table. Say if I run the query 5 times, this is how I expect the "moved" table to contain each time I run it.

```
1,2,3 --"moved" table has these rows 1st time when I run the query
4,5,1 --"moved" table has these rows 2nd time when I run the query
2,3,4 --"moved" table has these rows 3rd time when I run the query
5,1,2 --"moved" table has these rows 4th time when I run the query
3,4,5 --"moved" table has these rows 5th time when I run the query
1,2,3 --"moved" table has these rows 6th time when I run the query
```

...so the sequential read continues. Read sequentially from next row where it ended from last run.

I asked this already, but the answer works only partially. It doesn't work when the values in the "main" table grows or not in order.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause there is no order and _sequential_ has no meaning. What column do you want to use to specify the order of values to be taken from `@main`? (There only appears to be a single column and you don't like the results it provides.)

Comment: "Main" table is the base table and has only one column "RowID". And "Moved" table is the target table that also has only one column "RowID". I'm trying to read the rows top down and startover at the top again once it reaches the end of the table - recursive. The query could be anything as long as I get the given output above. Main table has that only column "RowID".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @main TABLE
(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DataID INT
)
DECLARE @selected TABLE
(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DataID INT
)

DECLARE @final TABLE
(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DataID INT
)

INSERT INTO @main values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)
--INSERT INTO @Selected values (1),(2),(3)
--INSERT INTO @Selected values (4),(5),(6)
--INSERT INTO @Selected values (7),(1),(2)
--INSERT INTO @Selected values (3),(4),(5)
INSERT INTO @Selected values (6),(7),(1)
--INSERT INTO @Selected values (2),(3),(4)
--INSERT INTO @Selected values (5),(6),(7)
--INSERT INTO @Selected values (1),(2),(3)

DECLARE 
    @LastDataID INT,
    @FinalCount INT

SELECT  
    TOP 1 
    @LastDataID = DataID 
FROM 
    @selected 
ORDER BY 
    RowID 
DESC 

INSERT INTO @final
    SELECT 
        TOP 3
        DataID
    FROM 
        @main
    WHERE
        DataID > @LastDataID 

SELECT @FinalCount = COUNT(1) FROM @final

IF (ISNULL(@FinalCount, 0 ) < 3)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @final
        SELECT 
            TOP (3 - @FinalCount)
            DataID
        FROM
            @main      
END

SELECT * FROM @final
```

The key was to have reference to the last record moved to the "moved/selected" table. It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The following example may give you a starting point. Note that there *must* be an explicit order provided for the values that you want to insert. A table has no natural order and "sequential" is meaningless.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Template as Table ( TemplateValue VarChar(10), TemplateRank Int );
-- NB: TemplateRank values are assumed to start at zero and be dense.
insert into @Template ( TemplateValue, TemplateRank ) values
  ( 'one', 0 ), ( 'two', 1 ), ( 'three', 2 ), ( 'four', 3 );
declare @NumberOfTemplateValues Int = ( select Max( TemplateRank ) from @Template ) + 1;
select * from @Template;

declare @AccumulatedStuff as Table ( Id Int Identity, Value VarChar(10) );
declare @GroupSize as Int = 5;

-- Add a block of   GroupSize   rows to the   AccumulatedStuff .
declare @LastValue as VarChar(10) = ( select top 1 Value from @AccumulatedStuff order by Id desc );
declare @LastRank as Int = ( select TemplateRank from @Template where TemplateValue = @LastValue );
select @LastValue as LastValue, @LastRank as LastRank;

with Numbers as (
  select 1 as Number
  union all
  select Number + 1
    from Numbers
    where Number < @GroupSize ),
  RankedValues as (
    select TemplateValue, TemplateRank
      from @Template as T inner join
        Numbers as N on ( N.Number + Coalesce( @LastRank, @NumberOfTemplateValues - 1 ) ) % @NumberOfTemplateValues = T.TemplateRank )
  insert into @AccumulatedStuff
    select TemplateValue from RankedValues;

select * from @AccumulatedStuff;

-- Repeat.
set @LastValue = ( select top 1 Value from @AccumulatedStuff order by Id desc );
set @LastRank = ( select TemplateRank from @Template where TemplateValue = @LastValue );
select @LastValue as LastValue, @LastRank as LastRank;

with Numbers as (
  select 1 as Number
  union all
  select Number + 1
    from Numbers
    where Number < @GroupSize ),
  RankedValues as (
    select TemplateValue, TemplateRank
      from @Template as T inner join
        Numbers as N on ( N.Number + Coalesce( @LastRank, @NumberOfTemplateValues - 1 ) ) % @NumberOfTemplateValues = T.TemplateRank )
  insert into @AccumulatedStuff
    select TemplateValue from RankedValues;

select * from @AccumulatedStuff;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and the code HABO! Really appreciate it. Just wanted it to be simple and not repeating in explicit loop. Sorry I couldn't explain my query clearly in my post, otherwise I'm sure by now you would have answered it. Figured out myself, posted the query below in case if you would like to understand what I was talking above. Sorry for my poor explanation. After having spent so many hours, I was kind of tiered. Thank you so much though!!!